# When does re-rendering actually happens?

Tags: reactjs, settimeout, rerender

Code:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Counter() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{number}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => {
        setNumber(number + 1);
        setTimeout(()=>setNumber(number + 1),2000);
        setTimeout(()=>setNumber(number + 1),5000);
      }}>+3</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

I went through [this saying `Setting state only changes it for the next render. During the first render, number was 0. This is why, in that render’s onClick handler, the value of number is still 0 even after setNumber(number + 1) was called`](https://react.dev/learn/state-as-a-snapshot#:%7E:text=Setting%20state%20only%20changes%20it%20for%20the%20next%20render.%20During%20the%20first%20render%2C%20number%20was%200.%20This%20is%20why%2C%20in%20that%20render%E2%80%99s%20onClick%20handler%2C%20the%20value%20of%20number%20is%20still%200%20even%20after%20setNumber(number%20%2B%201)%20was%20called) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73909783/where-does-the-function-continue-after-a-re-render) question already, so some understanding that I have is these calls are async hence the other code continues to run. But my doubt is when will re-rendering happen? For example in my code I know that making change as `number=>number+1` will give the desired result but shouldn't after `setNumber(number + 1);` this line re-render should occur but the next two lines are still in time out so they are still waiting, and when the rendering due to `setNumber(number + 1);` completes shouldn't they should see new value of number? What am I missing here?

Now next thing, say these all three lines are queued in some re-rendering queue, there will be re-rendering when the first queue entry resolves and then the next one sees the updated number value, why doesn't even this happens?
And why does `number=>number+1` solves the issue?

Comment: To begin with, you have three updates executed sequentially, updating to the same value though. `setTimeout` needs a callable, and now you just call `setNumber` immediately, followed by `setTimeout(undefined, 2000)` which does nothing (errors after 2 seconds? Not sure)

Comment: Hi, I've edited the code to remove the mistake, now I'm having a callback inside setTimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example in my code I know that making change as number=>number+1 will give the desired result but shouldn't after setNumber(number + 1); this line re-render should occur but the next two lines are still in time out so they are still waiting, and when the rendering due to setNumber(number + 1); completes shouldn't they should see new value of number? What am I missing here?

`number` is a snapshot of what the state was when this component rendered. As a `const`, it can *never* change. Even if you changed your code to `let`, calling `setNumber` does not even attempt to change your local variables, so it would still not change. So assuming `number` is currently 0, if you call `setNumber(number + 1)` three times, then you are calling `setNumber(1)` three times. You never call `setNumber(2)`.

When you change it to `setNumber(number => number + 1)`, you are no longer using your local variable, so the fact that it never changes doesn't matter.  React knows what the state actually is and will pass it into you. You can then calculate what the new state should be from that and return it. So the first time react passes in 0 and you return 1. Then react passes in 1 and you return 2, and finally react passes in 2 and you return 3.

In case the similar names are confusing things, note that the `number` in the `number => number + 1` is not the same thing as the `number` in `const [number, // ...`. You could rename the function argument to make this clearer, such as `setNumber(prev => prev + 1)`. `prev` is a new snapshot of the state which react passes into you.

> But my doubt is when will re-rendering happen?

I skipped this question because it kind of doesn't matter; the issue has entirely to do with stale closure variables, not with timing. But as for when the re-render happens: react waits until the current javascript execution stack finishes, and then if 1 or more states have changed, it does the render. You can think of it as though react is doing a `setTimeout(rerender, 0)` (though i'm not sure that's actually how it's implemented -- they may be using a microtask)

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, number is not a state, it's just a snapshot or kind of a deep copy of actual state, and setNumber changes the state not the number, but that number was already been use by other, and till the current execution stack finishes react doesn't re-render, also react always wait for execution stack to finish and then check for state change, but here our state change won't effect others because other were using the "snapshot" value. Did I got it right?

But what such happened in number=>number+1 that we started dealing with state instead of snapshot/local variable?

Comment: `So if I understood you correctly, number is not a state, it's just a snapshot` Correct. React has the real state, and while you were rendering, you assigned that state to a local variable. Changing the real state will not change your local snapshot of it. `But what such happened in number=>number+1 that we started dealing with state instead of snapshot/local variable?` That's how react designed `setNumber`. If you pass in a function, react will call that function and pass you the state. Basically giving you a new snapshot of it.

Comment: `kind of a deep copy of actual state` Btw, it's not a deep copy, just an assignment. Kind of like if you wrote `let realState = 0; const localState = realState; realState = 1;`

Answer (score 1):

When you use asynchronous functions (such as `setTimeout` or `Promise`) to trigger state updates, React does not batch them by default. This means that each `setState` call will cause a separate re-render, and the component will see the stale state value from the previous render. This is why you see only one re-render every click in your code.

According to [documentation](https://react.dev/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates#recap):

> Setting state does not change the variable in the existing render, but
> it requests a new render. React processes state updates after event
> handlers have finished running. This is called batching. To update
> some state multiple times in one event, you can use `setNumber(n => n + 1)` updater function.

So to fix this problem, you need to use a functional update instead of a direct state value. This means that you pass a function to setState that receives the previous state as an argument, and returns the new state based on it. This way, you always use the latest state value, regardless of batching or not. For example:

```
setNumber(number + 1);
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(`+2 stale state value: ${number}`);  // log stale state value
  setNumber((number) => number + 1);
}, 2000);
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(`+3 stale state value: ${number}`);  // log stale state value
  setNumber((number) => number + 1);
}, 5000);
```

You can see the whole example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-morse-dkrks2?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: `This is why you see only one re-render every click in your code`
I still don't get it, it doesn't matter if I have setTimeout or not it is only changing number once. But one state change will cause re-render and now other should be able to see that new changed value, why can't they?

Comment: @cheems, Did you see the logs in the setTimeout? They are logging the stale state value because setTimeout is executed after the current render cycle is finished. This means that it will see the state value from the previous render, not the current one. This is why you need to use a functional update instead of a direct state value when you want to update some state multiple times in one event. A functional update will always use the latest state value, regardless of batching or not. Please read it carefully and let me know if you have any questions. I hope this helps you understand concept.

Comment: Thanks a lot it really helped, but Nicholas answer made a lot more things clear so I'm accepting it, hope you don't mind.